# React-Redux - Using multiple container decorators

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 3 containers:

1. UserTask
2. UserMsg
3. UserNotify

Each have their own page in the app, but on the main page there is a drop down displaying all container data. Here is how I decorated the dropdown component:

```
@UserTaskContainer
@UserMessageContainer
@UserNotifyContainer
class ActivitiesDropdown extends React.Component {    
  ....    
  componentWillMount() {
    const allProps = this.props;
  }    
    ....
}

exports.ActivitiesDropdown = ActivitiesDropdown;
```

When debugging, all load data successfully and I see each's data being added to state, but in the ComponentWillMount, only the data from Notification state is present.

It appears, if I switch the decorators around, which ever is the last decorator is the one that shows up in props.

Question:

If I have a component that has multiple containers, how can I use the decorators to get all the states' props, or is there another way to acheive this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just curious, why multiple containers?

Comment: see 1st paragraph

Comment: I know, what I mean is you could achieve this without multiple separate containers connected if you break it apart differently... so I'm not sure why you would try to connect 3 containers to 1 component. You have a store state with all your information and your container provides said information, depending on how you have architected the state on your app. I don't see why you can't just create a single container for this component (if it is smart) and pass in the parts of the state you need?

Comment: can you show your decorators? it sounds like you're not passing down all the props, just the ones from that particular decorator.

Comment: found solution, will post in a minute or two, once I test a few things